# Can global unitaries create entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, work, quantum-entanglement

So I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4686), which states multiple times that:

> Indeed, global (and thus entangling) unitary operations
>   are capable of extracting more work than local operations from a set of quantum systems.

As seen the goal of the paper is to extract work from an isolated quantum system unitarily. If we consider just one system we find that there are *passive* states whose energy cannot be further lowered through unitary operations. (local unitaries = unitaries that act on one system at a time)

But then if we consider N copies of said passive states $\rho_p^{\otimes N}$ where $\rho_p$ is a passive state, we find that the global state is **no longer passive** even though the subsystems are.

So in order to extract this 'additional' work we cannot use local unitaries any more. But if we consider global, entangling unitaries that act on all subsystems simultaneously then we can we have access to this additional energy.

But as just mentioned using entangling unitaries implies that we might generate entanglement during the process.

And towards the end the 'conclusion' reads:

> So the farther $\sigma^{\mathrm{glo}}_{\mathrm{th}}$ is from $\sigma^{\mathrm{glo}}_p$ the more entanglement is generated and
>   more work is extracted.

where $\rho^{\mathrm{glo}}_p$ is the global state (which contains the locally passive states) and $\sigma^{\mathrm{glo}}_{\mathrm{th}}$ is the 'desired' state we want to get to, which is **globally passive**.

My question is: Is the **final state** entangled or was this entanglement only generated **during** the process, but vanished towards the end again such that there was no more entanglement present in the final state?

This is not clearly explained. I suspect that the entanglement vanishes towards the end....which begs the question: If the final state has no entanglement why do we even care that some was generated **during** the process?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Seconding Norbert's comment, what is the definition of "global" and "local" unitaries here, and what is the Hilbert space we're moving in?

Comment: just added more info

Comment: Aren't there two types of "global" unitaries: One acting on all copies on one side (Alice's system), and others acting on both A and B?

Comment: Are you asking generally? Because from my understanding a local operation would be sth. like $(U_A \otimes \mathbb{I}_B)\mid \psi_{AB}\rangle$ while a global would be $U_{AB}\mid \psi_{AB}\rangle$. That being said it might be possible to construct a 'global' unitary that only acts on one of the systems. But this was not really my question. My question is can these 'global' unitaries create entanglement or is entanglement generated only during a process but vanishes towards the end?